Can the dual of a symmetric power be shown to the the symmetric power of the dual using the permanent?
The answer to this question states that we have a nondegenerate pairing on a finite dimensional vector space $V$
$\wedge^k (V^*) × \wedge^k V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$
Given on pure exterior vectors by:
$(\alpha^1 \wedge \alpha^2 ... \alpha^k, v_1 \wedge v_2, ..., v_k) \rightarrow Det[\alpha^j, v_i]$
This implies that $(\wedge^k V)^* \cong \wedge^k (V*)$
Is there an analogue of this for symmetric powers using the permanant? Whilst the determinant of a $n × n$ matrix $A = (A^j_i)$ is given by:
$Det(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} sign(\sigma) \prod A^i_{\sigma i}$
The permanent drops the sign and is defined as:
$Pmt(A) = \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \prod A^i_{\sigma i}$
It is multilinear on row or column vectors and is symmetric. However, unlike the determinant it does not have a known geometric interpretation.
Is the following a nondegenerate pairing:
$\vee^k (V^*) × \vee^k V \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$
Given on pure symmetric vectors by:
$(\alpha^1 \vee \alpha^2 ... \alpha^k, v_1 \vee v_2, ..., v_k) \rightarrow Pmt[\alpha^j, v_i]$
and extended linearly? This would imply that $(\vee^k V)^* \cong \vee^k (V*)$
Whether these two spaces are isomorphic was asked on this Math.SE question but it didn't recieve an answer.

They are not isomorphic in general, only in characteristic greater than $k$. The issue is that one has to divide by $k!$. The pairing can be written down using derivations although this requires breaking the symmetry between $V$ and $V^{\ast}$. I don't know if it can also be written using the permanent.

Related to Qiaochu's comment: see the bottom paragraph on page 11 and the first four paragraphs on page 12 in https://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/tensor.pdf.

@QiaochuYuan: Apparently it can be written using the permanent. I've found a ref for this in Greub's Multilinear Algebra, section 4.11. He even makes the permanent fall out naturally rather than be imposed. I'll write up an answer once I fully understand the proof.

Caution: Greub works in characteristic zero.

@blargoner: I'm interested about applications of maths to physics, so I'm quite happy with the restriction to characteristic zero.

@MoziburUllah I see. If you end up liking Greub's books, you might find my notes and errata for them helpful.

@blargoner: Thanks. I'll take a look at them.
